# Securing up ubuntu on Amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, security

let's say you create a new instance on Amazon ec2 and you choose a default Ubuntu AMI. What things would you recommend for making the instance as secure as possible?

Elias

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly nebulous question with answers that span books.  It wouldn't matter where you were deploying to, you are talking about securing a Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

What purpose are you deploying it for? Is this a web server, database, something else? To Nathans point, you are mainly talking about securing a Linux sever.

Answer (score 0):

Elias: The quick answer is to decide which services you want to expose (ssh, http, https) and enable only those services on your machine.  I usually assign ssh to a non-standard port (something other than port 22), as I've noticed brute force attacks occur there.  Change the sshd port by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart the ssh service.  Keep in mind that you can have a service running on the machine but still exclude access to it from via your security group.

Consider [Fail2ban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban) or alternatives to deflect brute force ssh attempts.

Don't overlook the obvious.  I've watched attacks probe the standard LAMP stuff, checking for common passwords.  Create user accounts with: sudo adduser --disabled-password, then copy your public key to the instance.  Avoid services (ftp) that don't use a secure connection.  My preference is to run web services over https rather than http.

I've not even scratched the surface, but if you apply a few commonsense procedures, you should avoid the most common generic attacks.